# Is multiple regression appropriate?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, methodology

I am looking to conduct a research study and need some advice on potential statistics to analyze my data. I want to present problems of varying difficulty (easy, moderate, hard) to all participants. I also want to assess neuroticism as a continuous variable. My DV is also continuous variable (time to solve the problems). So, I want to assess the effect my repeated measures IV (problem difficulty) and the continuous variable (neuroticism) have on the time it takes to solve the problems. I have been poring over stat textbooks and websites trying to figure out the best statistical procedure. Should I do some kind of multiple regression? I am a novice to the area so any advice/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a regression or ANOVA based approach, but ANOVA seems particularly applicable here given your nominal (or perhaps ordinal) 'difficulty' factor. The ANOVA will tell you whether any IV or the interaction was significant, and post-hoc tests will allow you to identify how the trends manifest. A regression based approach can get you there too, but in a slightly more cumbersome way.

Comment: I had initially planned to use ANOVA, but didn't think it was appropriate because I have a continuous predictor variable.

Comment: I suppose I could do ANCOVA, with the continuous variable as covariate but I wonder if some kind of multiple regression is more appropriate